# Buck-Boost Waveforms

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost

I run a DC analysis of a buck-boost converter to generate the steady state waveforms of different currents and voltages. I am interested in the inductor current and voltage and capacitor current.

The circuit I have used to generate the waveforms is depicted below with **Vin** is a PWM signal.
[image]

The waveforms generated are shown below [image]

If we look closer to the waveform of VL (In red), we notice that VL is decreasing during the **ON Time**. But since it is connected in parallel to Vin during the **ON Time**, I expect to get a flat inductor voltage during this time. Why do I get a decreasing voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it isn’t directly connected to the input voltage waveform but via a diode and, as the inductor charges, the current increases and the forward diode volt drop also increases thus, the inductor voltage has a downward slope.

As much as you may protest that the diode is supposedly ideal, it isn’t.

Comment: Even though the diode is Ideal ?

Comment: It may be ideal in some respect but, regarding forward volt drop it absolutely cannot be. Forget about the slope - there’s about 2 or 3 volts difference between the pwm voltage and VL. That doesn’t occur with an ideal diode. You should use voltage controlled switches for this experiment.